# Use an IF-Else Statement Correctly

Tags: vba

I use the above equations in my code to provide a value in Column M.

Now i need to use an "IF-ELSE" statement to pull the value from column M and return the correct corresponding value in Column N.

However, my code keeps taking the value only from Column "N2" and is returning it to all the values in column N.

How do i get the 'IF-ELSE" statement to return adjacent values i.e

(M2-->N2)
(M3-->N3) and so on and so forth

```
Option Explicit
Sub STADPROJ()
Dim lastrow As Long

lastrow = Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Range("H2:H" & lastrow).Formula = ("=G2 * 1.2")
Range("I2:I" & lastrow).Formula = ("=H2 * 1.5")
Range("J2:J" & lastrow).Formula = ("=I2 * 0.8")
Range("K2:K" & lastrow).Formula = ("=J2 * 1")
Range("L2:L" & lastrow).Formula = "=SUM(G2:K2)"
Range("M2:M" & lastrow).Formula = "=(F2 - L2)"

If Range("M2") < 200 Then
    Range("N2:N" & lastrow) = 1008
Else
    Range("N2:N" & lastrow) = 0
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I helped you with this code earlier this week and I can see that you ended up using some of the code I provided and then deleted your post instead of accepting the solution and giving credit to people who have helped you. You should accept solutions from those who have volunteered their time to **your** problem......

Comment: @underboy, seems like he stroke again!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a VBA `If ... Else` construct, use a formula. So replace:

```
If Range("M2") < 200 Then
    Range("N2:N" & lastrow) = 1008
Else
    Range("N2:N" & lastrow) = 0
End If
```

with:

```
Range("N2:N" & lastrow) = "=IF(M2 < 200, 1008, 0)"
```

Comment: I actually just got it using a loop..thank you though!

Comment: Why do you prefer a loop over a formula? You did not use a loop for the other assignments either... Be aware that there is a good reason for not using a loop: it is much slower than a formula.

Comment: If I'm being honest its not prefer - I just didn't know there was an easier option. I'm extremely new to VBA and I'm just trying to build something for work to help me with the practical application of it all. Learning and watching vids only go so far

Comment: @Zeek77 most people would consider the approach you're taking more complex than simply using a formula. Best of luck in your learning.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a formula again:

```
Range("N2:N" & lastrow).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1] <200, 1008, 0 )"
```

Or, if you want to have only resulting values in column N:

```
With Range("N2:N" & lastrow)
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1] <200, 1008, 0 )"
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

Comment: I actually just got it using a loop..thank you though!